# Can't get output of a netcat command when launched with cron

Tags: cron, stderr, netcat

I need to retrieve some data with a netcat command every 2 seconds.
I use cron, here is the crontable:

```
# m h dom mon dow command
* * * * * /root/.mldonkey/stats/stats_parse
```

The script:

```
#!/opt/bin/bash
cd /root/.mldonkey/stats

for((i=0; i<29;i++)) do
    text=$(./mldonkey_command)
    echo $text >> test
    sleep 2
done
#Then I use the text variable
```

The mldonkey_command file:

```
#!/opt/bin/bash
nc 127.0.0.1 4000 <<EOF
auth user password
uploaders
q
```

The problem is: when stats_parse is launched manually, the right output is in test.
When launched whith cron, there is no output ($text is an empty string) although mldonkey_command is running.
All files have execution rights, the owner is root.

I think the problm is that nc writes to stderr, but I don't know ho to fix my issue.